# Conditionally apply tensor operations in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I know PyTorch doesn't have a `map`-like function to apply a function to each element of a tensor. So, could I do something like the following without a `map`-like function in PyTorch?

```
if tensor_a * tensor_b.matmul(tensor_c) < 1:
    return -tensor_a*tensor_b
else:
    return 0
```

This would work if the tensors were 1D. However, I need this to work when `tensor_b` is 2D (`tensor_a` needs to be `unsqueeze`d in the `return` statement). This means a 2D tensor should be returned where some of the rows will be `0` vectors.

Happy to use the latest features of the most recent Python version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to return a tensor either way (hence the mapping) but by checking the condition element-wise. Assuming the shapes of  `tensor_a`, `tensor_b`, and `tensor_c` are all two dimensional, as in "simple matrices", here is a possible solution.

What you're looking for is probably [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html), it's fairly close to a mapping where based on a condition, it will return one value or another *element-wise*.

It works like `torch.where(condition, value_if, value_else)` where all three tensors have the same shape (`value_if` and `value_else` can actually be floats which will be cast to tensors, filled with the same value). Also, `condition` is a *bool* tensor which defines which value to assign to the outputted tensor: it's a boolean mask.

For the purpose of this example, I have used random tensors:

```
>>> a = torch.rand(2, 2, dtype=float)*100
>>> b = torch.rand(2, 2, dtype=float)*0.01
>>> c = torch.rand(2, 2, dtype=float)*10

>>> torch.where(a*(b@c) < 1, -a*b, 0.)
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000, -0.0183]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

More generally though, this will work if `tensor_a` and `tensor_b` have a shape of `(m, n)`, and `tensor_c` has a shape of `(n, m)` because of the operation constraints. In your experiment I'm guessing you only had columns.

Comment: This works, thank you. But I'm not sure how efficient it is. Does `-a*b` get calculated for every element, even when `a*(b@c) >= 1` (I like the `@` operator)? For some situations, this could be a problem for me. In this particular situation, the condition will be more work than `-a*b`.

Comment: All arguments get evaluated before they are passed to the function, so `-a*b` gets computed once and is then used by `torch.where`, if that's what you're asking. Same for tensor `a*(b@c) < 1`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. Was hoping for an answer where `-a*b` wouldn't be evaluated unless the condition was true. I ended up simply multiplying element-wise the conditions vector by the 2D matrix instead of using `torch.where`, but your answer also would've worked.

Comment: You mean only computing elements `(-a*b)[i, j]` where `(a*(b@c) < 1)[i, j]` is *true*?

Comment: Yes, but only the ith row. a*(b@c) < 1 is a vector of 1D values